# Change orientation of existing PDF document (portrait/landscape)

Tags: java, pdf, itext, pdfbox

Is it possible to change the orientation of an existing document from 'portrait' to 'landscape' or vise versa?

I've tried copying a page (in portrait mode) to a newly created page (in landscape mode) using iText but it didn't work, the page orientation of the copied page was used.

Here's the code I used:

```
PdfReader originalFileReader = new PdfReader(src);

Document landscapeDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4.rotate());

PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(landscapeDoc, new FileOutputStream("/home/user/landscape.pdf"));

landscapeDoc.open();

for (int i = 1; i <= originalFileReader.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
     copy.addPage(copy.getImportedPage(originalFileReader, i));
}

landscapeDoc.close();
```

Comment: Is it ok to have part of the page cut off or are you hoping for a re-layout?

Comment: Actually, the underlying content of the PDF in portrait mode is cut off by the page itself and I think that it would fit on a page in portrait mode. So either solution would help I guess.

Comment: Can you share the document in question? Your description suggests that a different solution than copying is what you should use: change of mediabox/cropbox.

Comment: Why the pdfbox label?

Comment: @TilmanHausherr If there exists a solution with PDFBox, I would take that as well

Comment: In PDFBox, just call `doc.getPage(n).setMediaBox(new PDRectangle(doc.getMediaBox().getHeight(),doc.getMediaBox().getWidth())` and do the same for cropbox if it exists.

Comment: Cropbox returns mediabox if it doesn''t exist, so it would be better to store both first, and then do the re-assigment described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting a page from the original file and adding it to the copy doesn't re-layout the page.  If you get a landscape page at all, it will simply contain a copy of the original page clipped to the height of the landscape page.

Looking at the [iText site](https://itextpdf.com/support) it appears that the 2 closest use-cases to what you want are extracting data fields (marked up using a template) from a PDF to an XML structure ([pdf2Data](https://itextpdf.com/itext7/pdf2Data)) and adding content (watermarks, images, annotations, etc.) to an existing PDF.  (Lots of examples [here](https://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-6).)

There's nothing there about intelligently pulling content and formatting from a PDF and re-laying it out in a different PDF.  (Which would be an *extremely* hard problem anyway.)